# Using the directory API to turn off contact sharing for an organisation (G Suite)

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Google currently has a global setting to turn on and off contact sharing the directory, which means I cannot turn it off for a specific organisation.

In an education environment with staff and students, we do not want students to show up in the global directory, this can be achieved by manually turning them off or using GAM.

Instead we would like to do it programmatically using the Google Admin SDK or the Google Directory API, as seen [here](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/08/unshare-domain-users-contact.html).

I am unsure, how to do this, I don't know where to start. All I have done is start to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/get-start/getting-started) to point me in the right direction. But would like some further assistance on using the API and specifically running a script to do what I wanted above.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.